# Find the intersection of a vector and cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a vector, let say `as=[1 3 4]` and I have  `30 by 30` cell array. I want to check if the elements of vector `as` intersect with the elements of each cell or not? If so, I want to find the indices of the cell.

Comment: Is each cell of the cell array a `1 x 3` numeric array?

Comment: yes, it is a numerical array

Comment: And by `intersect`, don't you mean being `equal` instead? Or else how would you define `intersect`?

Comment: I mean by intersect is that if there is at least one element in the vector (as) exist in the cell, no need for both to be equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `cellarr` to be input cell array, see if this approach works for you -

```
%// Find intersecting elements for each cell
int_idx = cellfun(@(x) intersect(x,as),cellarr,'UniformOutput', false)

%// Find non empty cells that denote intersecting cells.
%// Then, find their row and column indices
[row_ind,col_ind] = find(~cellfun('isempty',int_idx))
```

---

Another approach with `ismember` to find matches among each cell and if there is `any` match within a cell, find the indices of it -

```
[row_ind,col_ind] =find(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) any(ismember(x,as)),cellarr,'un', 0)))
```

---

And another -

```
%// Vertically concatenate all numeric array from cells
vertcat_cells = vertcat(cellarr{:})

%// Get all good matches
matches = any(any(bsxfun(@eq,vertcat_cells,permute(as,[1 3 2])),2),3)

%// Reshape matches into the size of cellarr and get indices of matches
[row_ind,col_ind] = find(reshape(matches,size(cellarr)))
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see which one of the approaches works most efficiently (performance-wise).

Comment: How can we extend the previous code so I can find the intersection for each row in the cell instead of 1 row as previously.

Comment: @joanna So you mean you have 2D arrays in each cell now? If so, do all cells have same sized 2D arrays? What's the size of those 2D arrays?

Comment: No the cells may not have the same dimension, their dimensions are n by 2 (where n could be 1,2,3,4,... etc)

Comment: @joanna So, if there is at least one match in any of those rows, it should output the index of that cell?

Comment: if the row has an intersection with that vector, it should return (1 or 0) & if the row has no intersection with that vector, it should return (0 or 1).